# Integrate OpenStreetMap on WordPress

Tags: posts, pages, javascript

I want to put a map (using OpenStreetMap and OpenLayers) on a WordPress page. I don't want to use a plugin, because I have some specific operations I want to do with the map, and thus I want to stay the most flexible that I can.
I followed this tutorial : http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Wordpress#Manually_embedding_osm_maps

However, nothing happens on the page, it appears empty (only the name of the page, shaped with the theme I use (twentyfourteen, a classic, ideal for tests)). The code works on a local website.

Here is my script (contained in map_test.js):

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('basicMap');

var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
// Transform from WGS 1984
var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
// to Spherical Mercator Projection
var centerPosition = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-85.00,38.00).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
var zoom = 5;

map.addLayer(mapnik);
map.setCenter(centerPosition, zoom);
```

Here is the header.php piece of code that had to be modified :

```
<head>
    [...]
    <script src="../../plugins/Fidu-interactive-map/OpenLayers-2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../plugins/Fidu-interactive-map/js/map_test.js"></script>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

The WordPress page is empty, only containing this code :

```
<div id="basicMap"><p>OSM map</p></div>
```

I think my problem may be because of the path I specified in the header.php file. Indeed, the JavaScript files are contained in a plugin, which is activated. I started on the wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen directory to specify my path, because header.php is there, but maybe I was wrong.

Does someone have an idea of my problem and how to resolve it ?
Thanks !

Comment: Check the source to see what the absolute URL is that is generated by header.php, if that's incorrect then take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: just don't use relative urls. not sure if tha is your problem but it will help you to live longer

Comment: Also, [enqueue scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) rather than dropping them in the header right away. This solves the relative/absolute url question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally managed to get it working, my map now displays, thanks to you people.
What I did is :

- I changed the path to the absolute path of the scripts. Indeed, using a relative URL was a bad idea.
- I have changed my script, which now looks like that :

  ```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
  {
      map_init();
  }, false);

  var map;

  function map_init(){
      map = new OpenLayers.Map('basicMap');

      var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
      var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
      // Transform from WGS 1984
      var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
      // to Spherical Mercator Projection
      var centerPosition = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-85.00,38.00).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
      var zoom = 5;

      map.addLayer(mapnik);
      map.setCenter(centerPosition, zoom);
  }
  ```
- I removed the  that I had declared in the header, because it was now useless. Indeed, in the php file of my plugin, I put the two scripts and it works, because one of them catches the page opening.
- I now call the php file where my scripts are declared by using a shortcode on my page.

However, I tried to enqueue the scripts and removing the  from my php page, but it does not work. I'm not familiar with this technique, is there something more I have to do ?
Here is the piece of code :

```
function add_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('map_init', '/wp-content/plugins/Fidu-interactive-map/js/map_init.js');
    wp_register_script('OpenLayers', '/wp-content/plugins/Fidu-interactive-map/OpenLayers-2.13.1/OpenLayers.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('map_init');
    wp_enqueue_script('OpenLayers');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

Comment: the order is backwards in your enqueue function, the init script has to appear after the other script, since you have not set dependency.

Comment: I tried to change the order, but no luck, it doesn't work either.